# Import and export sqlite database in iOS

Tags: python, ios, core-data, sqlite, export

I'm trying to synchronize two sqlite core data databases and putting them back on device (2 iPads). For that I'm writing a script in Python in order to:

- 1) copy/export 2 "store.data" databases corresponding to Core Data DB from each device. They derive and use the same model.
- 2) creating a new database after merging them --> I wrote a Python script that is working (with union sqlite3 function). I have a "newDatabase" that includes both databases without duplication.
- 3) I need to put this "newDatabase" back on both devices, erasing the old ones. Both will be the same.

My problem is that I don't know how I can do that just in one click. I need to get the full pathname of the store.data file. I tried the `[[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject]` to get the path but I am not sure if it is the same on real device. Second, I am not sure how I can use it. Should I save it somewhere on launching the app and then look up for it in my script and use again to save the new database?

If anyone has already been looking for something like this or knows how to deal with copy/export file, it would be great.

Comment: Are you talking about a Python script that will run on a jailbroken device, or on a desktop computer? What application created the Core Data sqlite files you are attempting to work with? How are you going to work around the encryption?

Comment: It will work on a desktop computer. I would like to import the "store.data" Core Data file running on each device to the desktop computer (from where I am runnung the python script). I did not understand the question about the encryption. I can open these sqlite files and modify them with sqlite browser and it works... is it different in the "real" life? I don't think I click something in my app in xCode to encrypt them... Thanks

Comment: Core Data files are encrypted by default using NSFileProtection.

Comment: You mean on a real device? Because I can see the content of my database on my desktop computer by opening it with a browser. Any idea how I could get access the database file of my app running on a device from a desktop computer?